# JPA generating duplicate keys

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities defined as:

```
@Entity
public class FileMaster implements java.io.Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long fileId;

@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
private String fileNumber = "";
private String subject = "";

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date=null;
private String authPerson="";
private String authDesign="";
private String department="";


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fileMaster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="id") 
private Set<FileDetail> fileDetail = new HashSet<FileDetail>();
```

and second entity:

```
@Entity
public class FileDetail implements java.io.Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long pdfId;

//@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
private String name;

//@NotNull
@ManyToOne 
private FileMaster fileMaster;
```

the following code simply tries to persist the two master-detail tables.. First insert goes well and it commits the record:

```
Set<FileDetail> pdfFileNames = newUpload.getPdfFileNames();
EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("fms")                
                        .createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
FileMaster fileMaster = new FileMaster();

fileMaster.setFileNumber((String) editorForm.getField("fileNumber").getValue());
fileMaster.setSubject((String) editorForm.getField("subject").getValue());
fileMaster.setAuthDesign((String) 
editorForm.getField("authDesign").getValue());
fileMaster.setAuthPerson((String) editorForm.getField("authPerson").getValue());
fileMaster.setDate((Date) editorForm.getField("date").getValue());
fileMaster.setFileDetail(pdfFileNames);
em.persist(fileMaster);

Iterator<FileDetail> iter = pdfFileNames.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()) {
    FileDetail fileDetail = iter.next();        
    fileDetail.setName(fileDetail.getName());
    fileDetail.setFileMaster(fileMaster);
    em.persist(fileDetail);     
    }           
em.getTransaction().commit();    
em.close();
```

When I try to insert the second record.... It gives me PSQLException. Since Iam new to JPA... BTW Iam using Eclipselink and PostgreSQL with JPA....Iam finding it hard to resolve this issue. Could anyone please help me over this issue... let me paste the traces as well...

```
 May 27, 2012 10:08:02 AM com.vaadin.Application terminalError
 SEVERE: Terminal error:
 com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException
 Cause: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse                          Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913):      org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value     violates unique constraint "filedetail_pkey"
Detail: Key (pdfid)=(306) already exists.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO FILEDETAIL (PDFID, NAME, FILEMASTER_FILEID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [306, Manning Java Persistence with Hibernate 2nd.pdf, 3]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Manning Java Persistence with Hibernate 2nd.pdf)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:532)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:550)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:217)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1451)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1399)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1318)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:763)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:296)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:851)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse        Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913):    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value  violates unique constraint "filedetail_pkey"
Detail: Key (pdfid)=(306) already exists.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO FILEDETAIL (PDFID, NAME, FILEMASTER_FILEID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [306, Manning Java Persistence with Hibernate 2nd.pdf, 3]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Manning Java Persistence with Hibernate 2nd.pdf)
at    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(Entit yTransactionImpl.java:102)
at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransac tionImpl.java:63)
at com.complete.raspberry.webui.PersonEditor.save(PersonEditor.java:178)
at com.complete.raspberry.webui.PersonEditor.buttonClick(PersonEditor.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:512)
... 36 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` to generate `pdfid` using auto increment instead of `GenerationType.AUTO` for `FileDetail` entity.

```
@Entity
public class FileDetail implements java.io.Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long pdfId;
}
```

**GenerationType.IDENTITY**

> Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for
>   the entity using a database identity column.

Comment: I mean  I have tried AUTO, IDENTITY, TABLE, SEQUENCE...none of them have worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try setting logging on finest to see what is occurring.

Where does pdfFileNames come from?  Are this existing objects, with existing ids?  If they are existing, you should either be find/merging them, or create new ones with null ids.  Ensure they do not have existing ids when you call persist.

If using SEQUENCE also ensure your increment matches your allocation size (default is 50).

Comment: How could I insure they do not have existing ids... newUpload.getPdfFileNames() returns pdfFileNames Set and each FileDetail object in this Set has only name being set when a new file gets uploaded.