# JPA 2, understanding CascadeType.ALL and GenerationType.AUTO (EclipseLink 2.5)

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am having trouble to understand how properly persist entities with sub-entities when the JVM has been restarted and the database already contains data from previous sessions.

I have roughly the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Organization {
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "\"ADDRESS_ID\"", nullable = false)
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "\"ADDRESS_ID\"")
    private int addressId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "\"ADDRESS_TYPE_ID\"", nullable = false)
    private AddressType addressType;
}

@Entity
public class AddressType {
    ...
    // Not bi-directional, so nothing special here
}
```

It is excpected that the address types are present in the database (CascadeType.MERGE) before creating an address. A new organization is created with a new address and the address has a type set from the given selection. => This works ok when there is a clean database (only address types present).

Still developing, so every now and then I do shutdown the server (JVM) and restarted the application. Then I want to add a new organization to database which already contains data persisted in previous sessions, then I get the following error:

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL151120084237691' defined on 'ADDRESS'.
>   Error Code: -20001
>   Call: INSERT INTO "ADDRESS" ("ADDRESS_ID", "STREET_ADDRESS", "COUNTRY", "ZIP_CODE", "CITY", "ADDRESS_TYPE_ID") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>       bind => [2, testroad 1, Country, 99999, testcity, ABCDEF-123456]

It tries to use the same ID as already exists in the database. How do I make it realize that the id is already used and it should continue from last?

Notes:
- The address is persisted as part of the organization (CascadeType.ALL) not separately.
- In tests, I am loading all the existing organiztations to the same EntityManager that does the persisting operation => The organization has its addresses accessed eagerly, so they should be available in the em-cache. The duplicate address_id it complains about in unit tests seems to be an orphan entity (maybe this is the reason of the error actually?).
- I can get this error in unit tests using Derby, but a test server using Oracle DB has these same errors in log.
- I also tried adding a 'find all' query to load all address-entities into the cache of the same EntityManager that does the persisting operation of organization. The 'find all' is executed is before the persisting is done => it still failed.

// UPDATE
This same thing happens even that I use TableGenerator to get the id values.

```
@Entity
public class Address {
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "addr_gen")
    @TableGenerator(name = "addr_gen", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100, table = "\"ADDRESS_GEN\"")
    @Column(name = "\"ADDRESS_ID\"")
    private int osoiteId;
    ...
}
```

The generator table gets created, but it remains empty. The id's however start running from the initial value of '100'.

Some more notes:
- When using self defined table and inserting a value there for the sequence, the id for address-entities continues correctly from that value. When the test is finsihed, the table gets emptied while there still remains data in the tables => Will fail next time.
- When using GenerationType.AUTO, the sequence table gets a default sequence, but after tests it is cleared (same thing as with self defined table)

^I guess this has happened in test servers and it can be duplicated by not emptying the database after test. However the sequence table gets emptied. So the question would be, how to synchronize the sequence table after JVM boot (or prevent it from not emptying itself)?

Comment: This one looks about the same question. No answers there either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771903/jpa-generating-duplicate-keys

Comment: AUTO will likely default to Table sequences, so the issue is probably the same for both your tests - Check the SQL in the logs by turning the log level to finest, and show the statement that is used to select and increment the value, as well as the statements for the insert to verify they are using separate connections.   Verify that you have defined a non-transactional datasource that can be used for sequencing so that the increment can occur in its own transaction.

Comment: @Chris I forgot to do follow up for this. Yes, it seemed to be the same for both cases. I do not understand how to use non-transactional data source for sequencing. Why do I need that? The sequence incerementation was not the problem, it was because the sequence it self did not persist.

Comment: A sequence object is a database construct that can be incremented outside of the active transaction.  AUTO defaults to Table and requires selects and inserts, which operate in the current transaction - meaning other threads will not see increments until the transaction commits.  This is why it requires a non-JTA datasource, so that these statements can be executed outside of any active transactions and take effect immediately for all threads/applications using the sequence table, and don't rollback if the transaction happens to rollback.

Comment: @Chris I found there was a rollback done in some cases => duplicate ids. But this happened after the sequence was already broken. How do I specify a non-JTA datasource for sequences? Is this is? https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html#CONNECTION_POOL_SEQUENCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this a good solution or even right in general for original topic, but I managed to make some kind of workaround by defining the sequences separately for all auto-generated id fields.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "addrSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "addrSeq", sequenceName = "addr_seq", allocationSize = 10)
@Column(name = "\"ADDRESS_ID\"")
private int addressId;
```

It seems to work, though I do not know why this behaves essentially differently than using 'AUTO'?
Is it normal that the default sequence is nulled when the server is restarted?